# DHCP: bad configuration fixed-address?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

My configuration of DHCP is:

```
dns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
pool {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.0.1.255;
    option routers 192.0.1.1;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    range 192.0.1.231 192.0.1.231;
    host host_1 {
        hardware ethernet 5C:DC:96:04:1C:CA;
        fixed-address 192.0.1.231;
    }
    range 192.0.1.230 192.0.1.230;
    host host_2 {
        hardware ethernet 7C:01:91:1D:29:B9;
        fixed-address 192.0.1.230;
    }
    range 192.0.1.229 192.0.1.229;
    host host_3 {
        hardware ethernet 6C:88:14:DD:19:D0;
        fixed-address 192.0.1.229;
    }
    deny unknown-clients;
}
pool {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.0.1.255;
    option routers 192.0.1.1;
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    range 192.0.1.40 192.0.1.40;
    allow unknown-clients;
}
}
```

And my problem is that sometimes some user, for example, with MAC "6C:88:14:DD:19:D0" gets the IP 192.0.1.230 when should get the IP 192.0.1.229 ... what is the problem?.

I have these messages in my log system:

```
Feb  2 19:35:05 localhost dhcpd: Abandoning IP address 192.0.1.230: declined. 
Feb  2 19:35:05 localhost dhcpd: DHCPDECLINE of 192.0.1.230 from 6C:88:14:DD:19:D0 via enp14s0: abandoned
```

But the user 192.0.1.230 always have access to internet.